# Script to replace characters in Column

Tags: perl, shell

I was looking for some help replacing particular characters if based on the first 10 characters of a line. For example:

If the line is

```
test  (    2 ) [123456789]
```

I would like to replace it with

```
test  (    2 ) [123MMM789]
```

i.e, if the line starts with `test  (    2 )` replace columns 19,20,21 with M

if the line starts with anything else, it can be left as is. Thank you in advance!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Put forth something that resembles an effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a match and [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html):

```
while (<>) {
  substr($_, 19, 3) = 'MMM' if /^test  \(    2 \)/;
  print;
}
```

This can also be applied to the command line directly, since it is pretty simple:

```
$ perl -pe 'substr($_, 19, 3) = "MMM" if /^test  \(    2 \)/' file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! Follow up to that, how do i replace non consecutive characters?

Comment: @user1819450 you could use a full `if {}` and multiple `substr` assignments inside the if block ;-)